# C++ function definition error (parameter passing)

Tags: c++, function, parameters, parameter-passing

I'm trying to call my templated function with no success :(

My memaddr.h:

```
#ifndef __MEM_ADDR_WRITER__
#define __MEM_ADDR_WRITER__

#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <stdio.h>

namespace MemAddr {

    template <typename WRITABLE>
    int WriteMemoryAddress(const char* process, unsigned long address, WRITABLE value);

}

#endif
```

The call:

```
byte value = 0xEB;
MemAddr::WriteMemoryAddress("jamp.exe", 0x004392D2, value);
```

Error Message:

```
undefined reference to `int MemAddr::WriteMemoryAddress<unsigned char>(char const*, unsigned long, unsigned char)`
```

Answer: Templates needs to be defined in headers.. (@Shaggi)

Comment: Put the definition in the header file (templates needs this)

Comment: You're using a [reserved identifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Comment: Thanks @Shaggi, this was the right answer. But it is really stupid. My function needs another function from the header file (which does not use template), but i needed to define that too in header. So If I use templates, I must forget headers almost..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: Yeah its kinda weird but makes sense when you think about it (the compiler generates a new function for each different template parameter, it needs the source for this).
You shouldn't have a problem with non-templates though?

Answer (score 0):

The function template

```
template <typename WRITABLE>
int WriteMemoryAddress(const char* process, unsigned long address, WRITABLE value);
```

is not defined. Include its definition in the header file (memaddr.h):

```
template <typename WRITABLE>
int WriteMemoryAddress(const char* process, unsigned long address, WRITABLE value)
{
    /* do something */
}
```

The function template will be instantiated **once** when you use it.

Comment: please be more specific, template is built-in in c++ http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/